# Can vmware server be run on Windows Small Business Server 2008 (Premium) as a host?

Tags: vmware-esxi, windows-sbs-2008

Cannot seem to find a straight answer for this. Can SBS 08 Premium run vmware server? I read that SBS08 cannot be a Hyper-v host so I wonder if this would apply to vmware server too.

In a nutshell I am to perform a migration from SBS03 to 08 and will have the need to run a vm with 2003 for several apps that arent supported in 2008 (and an ISA alternative).

First idea was to run hyperv server with both the sbs and 2003 in vms, but im concerned about management since there are no vista or 2008 boxes on the network. Is Vmware Esxi an option?

Thanks in advance, 
Rob

Answer (score 2):

Yes, yes it can.

You can run VMWare Server on SBS08 or SBS08 on VMWare Server, you can also run SBS08 on ESX/ESXi and although you can run ESX/ESXi (4) in VMWare Server on SBS08 I really, really wouldn't. Really.

Answer (score 0):

I would think so. I dont see why it would not. If not, you can use others to virtualize OS's on SMB. This is a basic technology now so almost any virtual software work fine.

Comment: Thanks for both reponses above. Still unsure though at present which way to go about this. Choice is run sbs as the host and vmware on top or exsi on the bare metal. 

What are my remote management options like with exsi?

Comment: I believe that if you run ESXi on bare metal, you'll lose the ability to run SBS's native backup...if that's something you want.  (backup is designed for USB removable drives)

Comment: That will rule that one out then: we were planning to use BackupAssist with usb drives. I'll take my chances with vmware server running on sbs08 as the host.